# Is there a way to get the Database tab in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ and I use H2 database file (.mv.db) and I need to only view its contents whenever I add something in it. I thought I'd be able to file 'Database' tab in IntelliJ but I didn't find it.

**This is what I want** (image below)

[image]

When I click "View --> tool Windows" I don't see a database option (image below)

[image]

I am using Maven, is it possible that a certain plugin I downloaded somehow blocked/removed the database option?

I know there's 'Database Navigator' that I can download as a plugin, but its support for JDBC including H2 is experimental. So it's not a good choice for me. I can't seem to find the database plugin, is there any way to obtain it?

Comment: You most likely don't have the database option under View if you're running IntelliJ community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Database tools are a commercial feature, supported in *Ultimate* edition only.

See the [comparison of *Community* versus *Ultimate*](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) editions.

The [database tools functionality](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/features/) is also available as a separate product, [*DataGrip*](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/).